# file.createNewFile() gives java.io.IOException: Not a directory

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been getting a `java.io.IOException: Not a directory` exception for the following code:

```
fun saveImage(IdNumber: Int, photoFile: File, plantType: Int) {

    val newImage = PlantPhoto(IdNumber, "ZZ Plant", photoFile, plantType)

    val dir = File(
        context.getExternalFilesDir("planio/dataclasses/${plantType}").toString()
    )
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs()
    }

    val dataClassLocation = File(dir, "$IdNumber")

    if (dataClassLocation.exists()) {
        dataClassLocation.delete()
        dataClassLocation.createNewFile()
    } else{
        //exception occurs here 
        dataClassLocation.createNewFile()
    }

    val plantFile = FileOutputStream(dataClassLocation, true)
    val outStream = ObjectOutputStream(plantFile)

    outStream.writeObject(newImage)
    outStream.close()
    plantFile.close()
    Log.i(SaveTag, "Image saved successfully")
}
```

I have already checked that parent directories exist and since I am using an emulator that runs on API 29, `getExternalFilesDir` should not require permission to read and write to. But I am unsure as to why I am getting this exception since I should be able to create a new File inside another File as per [this link](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5779271-manage-your-data-to-have-a-100-offline-android-app-in-kotlin/5954921-create-a-file-on-external-storage).

Here is the stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
    at com.example.camera.presentation.CameraViewModel.saveImage(CameraViewModel.kt:68)
    at com.example.camera.presentation.CameraFragment$takePhoto$1.onImageSaved(CameraFragment.kt:167)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$3.onImageSaved(ImageCapture.java:661)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.lambda$postSuccess$0$ImageSaver(ImageSaver.java:253)
    at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageSaver$-JRZLUaKK7DQ1iBdZ_1qTGbYQrk.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Using @ALUFTW 's answer, I have modified my code to this:

```
    fun saveImage(IdNumber: Int, photoFile: File, plantType: Int) {

    val newImage = PlantPhoto(IdNumber, "ZZ Plant", photoFile, plantType)
    
    val dataClassLocation = File(context.getExternalFilesDir("planio/dataclasses/${plantType}/$IdNumber").toString())
    if (!dataClassLocation.exists()) {
        try {
            dataClassLocation.parentFile.mkdirs()
            dataClassLocation.createNewFile()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    val plantFile = FileOutputStream(dataClassLocation, true)
    val outStream = ObjectOutputStream(plantFile)

    // Method for serialization of object
    outStream.writeObject(newImage)
    outStream.close()
    plantFile.close()
    Log.i(SaveTag, "Image saved successfully")
}
```

And now I am getting a new `java.io.FileNotFoundException: planio/dataclasses/1/filename: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Check the return value of mkdir and handle accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, mkdirs returns false but I am confident that is because I have already made that directory during previous runtime attempts, and mkdirs only returns true if the directory was created and not if it exists or not. I also added 'Log.i(SaveTag, "${dir.absolutePath}")' and this also prints out the exact directory(file) I would like to save my files to. And I have also used Log.i(SaveTag, "${dir.exists()}") and this returned true.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: `returns false but I am confident that is because I have already made that directory during previous runtime attempts, a...` No. As you only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. Which is good. But not checking return value and not handle accordingly is not good. You are complaining about not being able to create a file. But before that the directory is not created.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: planio/dataclasses/1/filename: open failed` Of course. That is an impossible path.

Comment: `"planio/dataclasses/${plantType}/$IdNumber"` I think that it is not allowed to put a whole subdirectories train as parameter in getExternalFilesDir. Use only one subdirectory there.

Comment: Thank you, I have now separated the subdirectories and my code is now working :) But could you please elaborate on how to handle return values accordingly? All I have done is `Log.i(SaveTag, dirOne.isDirectory.toString())` but I don't know if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now separated my subdirectories and my code is working :)

Turns out it is not allowed to put a whole subdirectories train as parameter in `getExternalFilesDir`.

```
fun saveImage(IdNumber: Int, photoFile: File, plantType: Int) {

    val newImage = PlantPhoto(IdNumber, "ZZ Plant", photoFile, plantType)

    val dir = File(
        context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "planio/dataclasses"
    )
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs()
    }

    val dirOne = File(dir, "$plantType")

    if(!dirOne.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs()
    }

    val dataClassLocation = File(dirOne, "$IdNumber")

    if (dataClassLocation.exists()) {
        dataClassLocation.delete()
        dataClassLocation.createNewFile()
    } else{
        dataClassLocation.createNewFile()
    }


    val plantFile = FileOutputStream(dataClassLocation, true)
    val outStream = ObjectOutputStream(plantFile)

    outStream.writeObject(newImage)
    outStream.close()
    plantFile.close()
    Log.i(SaveTag, "Image saved successfully")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `dir.mkdirs()` isn't creating a directory for you.

If it won't work- It will not throw exception but it will **return false**.

Try the following code:

```
File dataClassLocation_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/planio/dataclasses/${plantType}/");
dataClassLocation_folder.mkdirs();
File dataClassLocation_file = new File(dataClassLocation_folder,filename);
dataClassLocation_file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not certain if java path strings require \/ or // since I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Comment: I am using windows and Android Studio 4.1.1

Comment: I have copy and pasted the code and it is giving me the following error through the catch  stack trace: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory. I think the directory exists but somehow createNewFile() isn't able to create a new File

Comment: oh! add this line before
file.getParentFile().mkdirs(). editted my answer.

Comment: Thank you, except now I am getting a new exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: planio/dataclasses/1/filename: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Edited my answer. Try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229430/discussion-between-aluftw-and-lisa).

Comment: You are also not checking the return value of mkdir. And you should only call it when the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: @blackapps - according to the chat discussion, Lisa's problem is not in the code but in the environment. She might change her question- since code that already worked to her stopped working. Also, we used mkdirs and not mkdir. mkdirs will create a directory only if it isn't created yet. so you can call this function even if the directory exists. According to the chat- it didn't created a directory (we checked it over there). So I'm guessing we will wait to Lisa's update :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```kotlin
    val dir = File(
        context.getExternalFilesDir("planio/dataclasses/${plantType}").toString()
    )
```

with:

```kotlin
    val dir = File(
        context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "planio/dataclasses/${plantType}"
    )
```

...and see if you have better luck. The parameter to `getExternalFilesDir()` is a Directory type (downloads, pictures, audio, etc) returning the root of the path from the environment, not a subdirectory path, this one you must create inside the root.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am still getting the exact same exception and stack trace as the first time `java.io.IOException: Not a directory`